# Why won't my code run? Pointers?

Tags: c, function, pointers, math

My code successfully compiles when I press F7 and is "successful", but won't execute when I build through F5 ("fails). I get a fatal LNK1120 error. I built it as a console application and used the cpp extension like I have done with my first 10 programs that I've ever written (first week programming, and I'm using the free C++ Visual Studio compiler offered by my institution)

Here's the code, it's supposed to teach modular programming and pointers. The program should take a number, and tell you its sign, whole part, and decimal part.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void separate(float num, char *signp, int *wholep, float *fracp);
int main(void)
{
    float value; 
    char sign;
    int whole;
    float fraction;

    printf("Please enter a value to evaluate\n");
    scanf("%f",&value);

    separate(value, &sign, &whole, &fraction);

    printf("The sign of your number is %c\n",sign);
    printf("The whole part in your number is %d\n",whole);
    printf("The fractional part in your number is %.4f\n",fraction);

return(0);
}
void seperate(float num, char *signp, int *wholep, float *fracp)
{
    float magnitude;

    if(num<0)
        *signp = '-';
    if(num==0)
        *signp = ' ';
    if(num>0)
        *signp = '+';

    magnitude=fabs(num);

    *wholep = floor(magnitude);
    *fracp = num-*wholep;
}
```

Comment: Yu has the answer below; but you could in future tell us what LNK1120 and the full error message *is*.

Answer (score 7):

There's a typo between `seperate` and `separate` in your function declarations and definitions.

Comment: I compiled the code on my system and it's giving an undefined reference to `separate`, this is definitely the issue.